# plaintext decrypted form a cipher text using key = 3 in Caesar Cipher and that plain text with the following ciphertext to get the key

Tags: encryption, decryption

[image]

how to use the plaintext from that was decrypted form a cipher text using key = 3 in Caesar Cipher and using that plain text with the following ciphertext to get the key.

Comment: for the second exercise: k=4, you have to arrange ciphertext in rail fence and then u can get plain text.

Answer (score 1):

- Take original plain text as " PLEASEEECUSEMYDEARAUNTSALLY", note that I've ignored the 'X', so that rail fence with key(row depth) = 4 cipher text will be "PEMALLEEEYRUALESCSDANSYAUET" now using Caesar cipher with k=4 on this new text.
- ${C= (P+k)mod26}$ , you will get cipher as $${"TIQEPPIBICVYEPIWGWHERWCEYIX"}$$
- [image: List item]

- Here we take row wise so P --> T, E-->I, M-->Q, A-->E, L-->P,
- in second row L-->P,E-->I and so on...

Comment: @user86282, Did you find the answer, if yes , then accept the answer.